# Case insensitive sorting with Firebase orderByChild

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, case-insensitive

I’m using a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to display a list of strings. My query uses orderByChild. The results sorts with capitalize letters first and looks like this:

Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, aItem, bItem, zItem.

How do I use orderByChild resulting in case insensitive sorting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't. Kind of.

If you have data you want to sort by but there also needs to be a user representation of that data, keep two versions

```
posts
  post_id_0
    display_version: William
    sort_version: william
  post_id_1
    display_version: Henry
    sort_version: henry
```

Of course you could read in all of the data from Firebase and use .toLower or whatever your platform call is and then sort in code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990161/how-to-search-using-lowercase-in-firebaserecycleroptions-in-android-java

Comment: check the above question bro, I too have that question

Comment: is there anyway to do search without case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your local data source such as `List` by using `sortBy()`:

```
firebaseUsers.sortBy { it.user.nickName.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) }
```