# Search Query by removing casesensetive in angularFire2?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

```
this.userData = this.af.database.list('/REPORTS',{
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'siteName',
      startAt: val,
      endAt:val+'\uf8ff' 
    }
});
```

Firebase returns data only when I'm giving first letter is in capital. But when I'm giving first letter as lowercase its returning null. I want that firebase should return the data on both condition either first letter is uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: The Firebase Database does not support case insensitive searches. You will have to come up with an alternate solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643459/case-insensitive-sorting-with-firebase-orderbychild, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590937/firebase-query-methods-startat-taking-case-sensitive-parameters